# ruby gem native extensions under msys2 failed

Tags: ruby, makefile, rubygems, msys2

I am trying to install several gems, some of which need to build native extensions.

The autogenerated Makefile, for some unknown reason, does not work as it should.
The resulting error is:

```
$ gem install ffi-yajl --verbose
 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libyajl2-1.2.0/lib/libyajl2/vendored-libyajl2/include -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -I/mingw64/include/ncurses -IC:/building/msys64/mingw64/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include
 -LC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/libyajl2-1.2.0/lib/libyajl2/vendored-libyajl2/lib -L. -pipe
creating Makefile
generating encoder-x64-mingw32.def
make: *** No rule to make target '/C/msys64/mingw64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby.h', needed by 'encoder.o'.  Stop.
ERROR:  Error installing ffi-yajl:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    Building has failed. See above output for more information on the failure.
make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/gem_make.out
HEAD https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=ffi-yajl
200 OK
Getting SRV record failed: DNS result has no information for _rubygems._tcp.api.rubygems.org
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=libyajl2
200 OK
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/LICENSE
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/README.md
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/Rakefile
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/bin/ffi-yajl-bench
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/ext/ffi_yajl/ext/dlopen/dlopen.c
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/ext/ffi_yajl/ext/dlopen/extconf.rb
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/ext/ffi_yajl/ext/encoder/encoder.c
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/ext/ffi_yajl/ext/encoder/extconf.rb
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/ext/ffi_yajl/ext/parser/extconf.rb
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/ext/ffi_yajl/ext/parser/parser.c
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl.rb
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/benchmark.rb
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/benchmark/MIT-LICENSE
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/benchmark/encode.rb
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/benchmark/encode_json_and_marshal.rb
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/benchmark/encode_json_and_yaml.rb
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/benchmark/encode_profile.rb
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/benchmark/http.rb
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/benchmark/parse.rb
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/benchmark/parse_json_and_marshal.rb
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/benchmark/parse_json_and_yaml.rb
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/benchmark/parse_profile.rb
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/benchmark/parse_profile_ruby_prof.rb
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/benchmark/parse_stream.rb
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/benchmark/subjects/item.json
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/benchmark/subjects/ohai.json
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/benchmark/subjects/ohai.marshal_dump
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/benchmark/subjects/ohai.yml
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/benchmark/subjects/twitter_search.json
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/benchmark/subjects/twitter_stream.json
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/benchmark/subjects/unicode.json
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/encoder.rb
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/ext.rb
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/ext/.keep
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/ffi.rb
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/ffi/encoder.rb
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/ffi/parser.rb
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/map_library_name.rb
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/parser.rb
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/platform.rb
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/lib/ffi_yajl/version.rb
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/spec/ffi_yajl/encoder_spec.rb
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/spec/ffi_yajl/map_library_name_spec.rb
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/spec/ffi_yajl/parser_spec.rb
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/spec/spec_helper.rb
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
current directory: C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/ext/ffi_yajl/ext/encoder
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160616-3960-1kb305r.rb extconf.rb
current directory: C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/ext/ffi_yajl/ext/encoder
make "DESTDIR=" clean
current directory: C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.2.3/ext/ffi_yajl/ext/encoder
make "DESTDIR="
```

When i step into this folder and execute the make by hand:

```
$ make
make: *** No rule to make target '/C/msys64/mingw64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby.h', needed by 'encoder.o'.  Stop.
```

Examining the problem even more closely:

```
$ ls -l /C/msys64/mingw64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 User None 868 Jul 11  2012 /C/msys64/mingw64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby.h
```

If i modify the Makefile slightly (remove the dependency on the headers for the objects) the obvious happens:

```
$ make
compiling encoder.c
encoder.c:1:18: fatal error: ruby.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:238: recipe for target 'encoder.o' failed
make: *** [encoder.o] Error 1
```

running the commands by hand (generated by `make -n`) gives no errors and compiles successfully. Unfortunately i can not use this hackery to build the gem.

The question then is: Why does the system not find the header when run by make, but does find it when using gcc directly?
What do i need to change?

Comment: Which platform / OS ? If you are on a Mac, you need xcode command line tools installed. If you are on *nix, you need devel tools and if on windows, you need devkit installed. Those will get the necessary binaries and compliers required and link them to ruby for gem installation without errors.

Comment: @Sam As msys2 suggests, i am on windows. it also does give me the necessary binaries, compilers and tools required to build and link them. As described the problem is, that the make and the compiler can't find the header files, allthough they are at present at the correct location.

Comment: You should install Ruby's header files.

Comment: @PooyanKhosravi As i wrote they are installed and at the location the compiler and make are looking for.

Comment: @scones: Are you still having this problem?  It worked for me on my MSYS2 installation.  Here is the output I got when I installed the gem: https://gist.github.com/DavidEGrayson/16857cf74265b139936849b963a72e06

Comment: @DavidGrayson Unfortunately i am unable to check, as i installed linux on my work machine by now. It might have been an issue with a prior installed ruby via ruby installer, which was not cleaned up with the uninstall properly, but this is pure speculation.